# Converting MySQL query to PostgreSQL. Order by day()?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I'm converting this code from MySQL into PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL doesn't have a `day()` function for my `Order by` to work. Is there a known solution? I'm wanting to group the results by day.

```
        {

        SELECT to_char(date, 'YYYY-mm-dd') AS date
        FROM \"users exercises\"
        WHERE userid = $user->id AND (date >= '$begin' AND date <= '$end')
        GROUP BY day(date)
        ORDER BY date

        ) UNION ALL (

        SELECT to_char(date, 'YYYY-mm-dd') AS date
        FROM \"users foods\"
        WHERE userid = $user->id AND (date >= '$begin' AND date <= '$end')
        GROUP BY day(date)
        ORDER BY date

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's `day()` returns the day of the month. The PostgreSQL [equivalent of that is](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```
GROUP BY extract(day from "date")
```

Comment: You've linked to the 8.2 manual. Better to link to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT